# What are the `'UnreadVariable'` in Tensorflow 2.0?

Tags: tensorflow, tensorflow2.0

In Tensorflow 2.0, some variables can be described as `'UnreadVariable'`

For ex:

```
b = tf.Variable([4,5], name="test")
print(b.assign([7, 9]))
# Will print
# <tf.Variable 'UnreadVariable' shape=(2,) dtype=int32, numpy=array([7, 9], dtype=int32)>
```

What does it mean?

Answer (score 1):

`UnreadVariable` basically `Represents a future for a read of a variable. Pretends to be the tensor if anyone looks.`

This is because of the eager execution enabled during assign operation.

TensorFlow's eager execution is an imperative programming environment that evaluates operations immediately, without building graphs: operations return concrete values instead of constructing a computational graph to run later.

In Tensorflow 2.0 eager execution is enabled by default. So the operation which you are performing does it without constructing a graph.

Anyways if you want you can change the type to `AssignVariableOp` by disabling eager execution as follows.

```
import tensorflow as tf
tf.compat.v1.disable_eager_execution()

b = tf.Variable([4,5], name="test")
print(b.assign([7, 9]))

Returns:  

<tf.Variable 'AssignVariableOp' shape=(2,) dtype=int32>
```

Comment: Since it's in eager mode, we shouldn't have any notion of `future for a read`, since the operation is done immediately?